# Não estou conseguindo chamar um .js externo para uma página html

Tags: javascript

Comecei muito recentemente a aprender sobre js, e estou tendo problemas em chamar um .js externo para a minha página html, procurei em vários lugares mas não achei nada além do erro que o navegador diz ter um 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' e eu não sei o que fazer. Desculpem se a pergunta sair meio desconfigurada ou estranha, é a minha primeira vez por aqui. O conteúdo do arquivo aula01.js está logo abaixo.

```
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>Aula 01-JS</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="aula01.js" ></script>
    </body>
</html>

Conteúdo do arquivo .js
alert('Esse é o meu primeiro código JS';
```

Comment: O arquivo aula01.js está na mesma pasta que o seu HTML? Qual o conteúdo desse arquivo aula01.js?

Comment: Sim os arquivos estão na mesma pasta, e o arquivo aula01.js tem um comando de alert

Comment: Edite a pergunta e coloque o conteúdo dele (js), por favor.

Comment: Pronto, editei.

Comment: Boa tarde, verifique a sintaxe da função e verá que o próprio alerta de erro está dando a solução...

Comment: Obrigado a vcs tmb e boa tarde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olha o seu erro

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing )

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Faltou um `)` depois de `...JS';`, deveria estar no final do script `JS' ) ;` o parentes

**Deveria ficar como abaixo**

```js
alert('Esse é o meu primeiro código JS');
```

Comment: Nossa nem tinha percebido, muito obrigado

Comment: @Chadii se resolver lembre-se de marcar a resposta como aceita clicando no ✔️ abaixo das setas ao lado da resposta, assim ela não fica em aberto mesmo com o problema já resolvido. Boa sorte nos estudo e atenção aos detalhes ;)

Comment: Resolveu sim, muito obrigado. Irei me atentar mais obrigado :D